# How to load an html file with <script> tag on a node js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an html file that has some javascript on script tag. I created a server with node js but when I try to load the website on the server I only get to see the html part of the file, and not the javascript part.

Here's a part of the code in html on the head tags that I tried to link it with javascript:

```
<head>
    <title>HTML5 Canvas Winning Wheel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Winwheel.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

And here is the app.js where I created the server:

```
var http = require('http');  
var url = require('url');  
var fs = require('fs'); 

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;  
    switch (path) {  
        case '/index.html':  
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data) {  
                if (error) {  
                    response.writeHead(404);  
                    response.write(error);  
                    response.end();  
                } else {  
                    response.writeHead(200, {  
                        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                    }); 
                    response.write(data);  
                    response.end();  
                }  
            });  
            break;  
        case '/Page2.html':  
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data) {  
                if (error) {  
                    response.writeHead(404);  
                    response.write(error);  
                    response.end();  
                } else {  
                    response.writeHead(200, {  
                        'Content-Type': 'text/html'  
                    });  
                    response.write(data);  
                    response.end();  
                }  
            });  
            break;  
        default:  
            response.writeHead(404);  
            response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");  
            response.end();  
            break;  
    }  
});

server.listen(8082);
```

Comment: Thank you Tarik! This was my first time ever asking a question. I wasn't familiar with how to use the features of stack overflow when asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you serve `index.html` client will try to get all resources specified in `index.html` from your server. You can see that if you log `path` variable in your callback function:

```
/index.html
/main.css
/Winwheel.js
/app.js
```

What you can do here is to make more switch cases for other files like `main.css` and `app.js` but this can get overwhelming if you have many files to serve.

Instead, take a look at how to serve static files from your server here:
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html or how to create simple express server here https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html.

If you don't won't to use express you can remove switch statement and do something like this:

```
var http = require('http');  
var url = require('url');  
var fs = require('fs');  
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;  
    fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data) {  
        if (error) {  
            response.writeHead(404);  
            response.write('This page does not exist');
            response.end();  
        } else {  
            response.writeHead(200, {  
                'Content-Type': 'text/html'
            }); 
            response.write(data);  
            response.end();  
        }  
    }); 
});  
server.listen(8082);
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir!! You have helped me quite a lot.